# Yocto complains about perl lib mistmatch

Tags: perl, build, yocto

I am trying to build an operating system using Yocto and the recipe keeps flaking out on a mismatch in Perl libs:

```
MiscXS.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xde00080, needed 0xdb80080)
```

When it is building qemu.

Any idea which what this actually means? Do I need to "downgrade" the perl libs on the build host?

Answer (score 0):

The build of Perl that is attempting to load the module is different than the build of Perl that installed (compiled) it.

[perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html):

> (P) A dynamic loading library `.so` or `.dll` was being loaded into the
>   process that was built against a different build of perl than the
>   said library was compiled against.  Reinstalling the XS module will
>   likely fix this error.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, is this on the build machine or is this target code? I am building on x86_64 for Armv7.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you installed a module using one `perl` and you use the module in a different `perl`, you can get this problem. You need to (re)install the module using the new `perl`.

Comment: The only time you don't is if you upgrade the release but not the version of `perl` (and use the same configuration for the new release as you used for the original release).